# Gurobi Constraint Creation with a subset

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to add the following constraint in Gurobi 7.0.2 via Python 2.7.12.

[image: \sum_{i\in I_j}c_i x_i \leq f_j~~~\forall j\in I]

I have a list of J as:

```
J

[u'Capability Investments',
 u'Facilities',
 u'Mission #1',
 u'Mission #2',
 u'New Program Readiness',
 u'Site Support',
 u'Transformation',
 u'Waste Mgt']
```

and my list I is:

```
I

[u'Capability Investments', u'Capability Investments', u'Capability Investments',
u'Capability Investments', u'Capability Investments', u'Site Support',
u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Site Support', 
u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Site Support', 
u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Site Support',
u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', 
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities', u'Facilities',
u'Mission #2', u'Mission #2', u'Mission #2', u'Mission #2', u'Waste Mgt', u'Waste Mgt',
u'Waste Mgt', u'Waste Mgt', u'Waste Mgt', u'Waste Mgt', u'Waste Mgt', u'Waste Mgt',
u'Waste Mgt', u'Waste Mgt', u'Waste Mgt', u'Waste Mgt', u'Waste Mgt', u'Transformation',
u'Transformation', u'Transformation', u'Transformation', u'Transformation',
u'Capability Investments', u'Mission #2', u'Mission #2', u'Mission #1', u'Mission #1', 
u'Mission #1', u'Mission #1', u'Mission #1', u'Mission #1', u'Facilities',
u'New Program Readiness', u'New Program Readiness', u'New Program Readiness',
u'Transformation', u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Site Support',
u'Site Support', u'Site Support', u'Mission #1']
```

My failing attempt:

```
for i in I:
    for j in J:
        if i == j:
            m.addConstr(quicksum(c[i]*x[i])<=f[j])
```

First  reason to fail is I have not enumerated my list, thus, this kind of constraint addition causes a conflict with the variable definition, i.e. my x variable is defined as x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3].... So, I cannot really use these names "Capability Investments, Facilities, etc." as my index. Any contribution is appreciated to resolve my problem.

Comment: Your list is a flat list, which doesn't match the formula.

Comment: I know it does not match @David, how can I make it work?

Comment: I enumerated my lists and created tuples: `J = list(enumerate(J))
I = list(enumerate(I))` But, still I couldn't apply your formula, which really makes sense, but does not work.

Comment: What I want to do in words is to sum over `i` which has the same elements in `J`, and then it is `<=` corresponding element in `I`. An example: assume `c_i=1` for all i. `x_0+x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_185 <= f_0`, where `f_0 = "Capability Investments"`. Similarly for `j = 1 = "Facilities"`, `x_23++x_24+...+x_162+x_194 <= f_1` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The formula in at the top of your post is written as

```
for j in J:
   m.addConstr(quicksum([c[i] * x[i] for i in I[j]]) <= f[j])
```

presuming you mean to index the set `J` by `j`.